# strapi admin not running in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, strapi

I just finished my project in Strapi and deployed in AWS, when I run my Public ipv4 :1337 says: 'server is running successully' but when I want to log in admin panel just spinning and not showing panel.

server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  cron: { enabled: true},
  url: env('URL', 'http://localhost'),
 admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET', 'MY_JWT_SECRET'),
    },
  },
});
```